# Why do I get this weird output?

Tags: java

I have three classes

```
public abstract class Champion 
{
    private String name;

    public Champion(String ChName)
    {
        name = ChName;

    }
    public void setName(String ChName)
    {
        name = ChName;
    }
    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

}
```

second:

```
public class Mage extends Champion {

    public Mage(String ChName)
    {
        super(ChName);
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return String.format("%s",super.toString());
    }
}
```

and my main:

```
public class JavaApplication2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
      Mage mage = new Mage("ori");
      System.out.println("champion is "+mage);          
    }

}
```

The output should be "champion is ori"
but I get:
"champion is javaapplication2.Mage@1fee6fc"

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to override `toString()` in `Champion` as the call to `super.toString()` in `Mage.toString()` will be calling `Object.toString()`.

Comment: Thank you Sir and sorry for your trouble. I shall remember to do this from now on.

Comment: @user1913592, no problem and apology unrequired.

Answer (score 0):

By calling `super.toString()` you call the `Object` `toString()` method, giving you the result you see.

You need to implement the `Champion` `toString()` method.